# Conversion of var to class type in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and was going through `ArrayList`. My question is can we store different datatype - different classes, different structures into ArrayList and access them. I could see that I can add them but I am not sure on how can we retrieve it. I tried retrieving by using the datatype name i.e. class name but I am seeing that the first member data is missing while I am printing the output. 
What concept am I missing here?

```
class OSPF_Area
{
    public string AreaId { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
    public int AreaNumberofRoutes { get; set; }
}

class OSPFLinkPacket
{
    public int LinkPacketCounts { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfHelloPacket { get; set; }
    public string LSAType { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OSPF_Area ospfArea1 = new OSPF_Area();
    ospfArea1.AreaId = "0.0.0.1";
    ospfArea1.AreaId = "non-backbone";
    ospfArea1.AreaNumberofRoutes = 14;

    OSPFLinkPacket ospfLink1 =  new OSPFLinkPacket();
    ospfLink1.LinkPacketCounts = 20;
    ospfLink1.LSAType = "Type4";
    ospfLink1.NumberOfHelloPacket = 40;

    ArrayList OSPFInfo = new ArrayList();

    OSPFInfo.Add(ospfLink1);
    OSPFInfo.Add(ospfArea1);

    foreach(var val in OSPFInfo)
    {
        if(val.GetType().Name == "OSPF_Area")
        {
            Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(OSPF_Area));
            OSPF_Area area = (OSPF_Area)val;
            Console.WriteLine(area.AreaId);
            Console.WriteLine(area.AreaName);
            Console.WriteLine(area.AreaNumberofRoutes);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output is:

> non-bacbone
>   14

I am not sure why the area-id didn't get printed.

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` rather than a `List<T>` for the relevant type, e.g. `List<OSPFLinkPacket>`? `ArrayList` has been effectively deprecated for new use since 2005...

Comment: A] `var` is a syntactic sugar keyword that just substitutes the correct data type on a compile; and B] Don't use `ArrayList`. Use `List`. You can thank me later.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, I'd advise you to not use `ArrayList`. Use `List<T>` where you can, although storing different types of objects in a list is a bit of an anti-pattern to start with.

`Convert.ChangeType` doesn't do anything for you, and you should use `is` or `as`. For example:

```
OSPF_Area area = val as OSPF_Area;
if (area != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(area.AreaId);
    Console.WriteLine(area.AreaName);
    Console.WriteLine(area.AreaNumberofRoutes);
}
```

The problem for the output is almost certainly due to the typo in the first lines of `Main`:

```
ospfArea1.AreaId = "0.0.0.1";
ospfArea1.AreaId = "non-backbone";
```

... you're not assigning anything to `AreaName`.

Comment: I do have to ask if there actually is a valid use for `ArrayList`. It seems to me like the one strength it could possibly have is being able to store different types in a single list, but even then you could just use `List<object>`. And in every other regard I can possibly think of, `List` is a preferable choice. I suppose maybe if the target .NET type is pre 2.0, but is that really a necessity anymore?

Comment: @Abion47: I don't think there's any reason to use it in *new* code - but I for one wouldn't want to break old code by removing it.